# How should we handle questions asking for specific legal advice?

Tags: discussion, policy

While questions that touch on the law are generally on-topic here at Game Development, there are subsets of that topic that I think we should clarify our position on.

In this case, I'd like to discuss questions that ask for *specific legal advice*. By that, I mean questions that lay out an asker's particular scenario in detail and solicit the community for guidance to handle that scenario or an interpretation as to whether that scenario violates some law.

How should we treat such questions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think we should [adopt Law SE's policy, which makes these questions off-topic](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/policy-for-questions-that-clearly-ask-for-specific-legal-advice).

As with anything we consider off-topic, if it's possible to edit a question into something that is on-topic (in this case, likely by making it more general and removing the aspects of the query that "personalize" it just to the asker), we should.

Similarly, if it's possible to close the question as a duplicate of an existing more-canonical form of the question, we should do that. We already have established this specific precedent for some such queries, such as the variety of questions pointing to "[How closely can a game legally resemble another?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/how-closely-can-a-game-legally-resemble-another)"

But providing detailed, customized legal guidance to a specific scenario isn't our wheelhouse, it isn't really within the realm of the site's responsibility (although the *broader shape* of the law around business of making games can be), and it shouldn't be something we entertain.