# Should we remap the "legal" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Continuing the trend of law-related meta questions... is there anything we can do to the [legal](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) tag to provide better guidance as to its use and the kinds of law-related questions that are acceptable here?

Or is it fine as it is?

Answer (score 8):

One thing I've been thinking we should do is merge it into a more specific tag to provide clearer guidance. *Especially* if we [adopt Law SE's policy on specific-advice legal questions](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2625/1430), inspection reveals that the majority of our law-related stuff concerns intellectual property. Copyright and trademark, most often.

We could remap [legal](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) to [intellectual-property](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intellectual-property) to more clearly indicate that that is the basic scope of the law questions we handle here.

Comment: I think this is a good suggestion, although I'd have something to say about the _implementation_ of this. I suggest that we manually remove the [tag:legal] from all the questions, re-adjust the tags appropriately and review them to close them if needed. _Then_, when there are no more questions tagged with `legal`, we create a synonym of [tag:legal] to [tag:intellectual-property]. This will be easier to review them like that compared to doing it [after the fact](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2515/) :p